# How to determine which Maven dependency is needing a missing dependency?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I am trying to build an old Maven project and I'm getting the error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.initech.myapp:war:${buildVersion}: Failure to find tangosol:tangosol-coherence:jar:3.3-rc1 in http://mvnrepo.initech.com/archiva/repository/initechrepo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of initechrepo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

I looked in the `pom.xml` of MyApp and there is no mention of "tangosol" and there is no parent POM so I figure this must be a transitive dependency.

*Normally*, I can use the [Maven Dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) on the command line with [`mvn dependency:tree`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) to display transitive dependencies. *However*, since the dependency is missing, the build fails and errors out instead of displaying the tree.

How can I get the cause of **missing** transitive dependency even if the build is failing?

---

**EDIT:** I am aware of **why** it failed, the artifact *is* missing from our local repository *and* the central repository, the question is which of my dependencies is asking for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There should be a better way, *but* if you run the command in debug mode (ie `-X` so the full command becomes `mvn -X dependency:tree`) then you'll see the trace printed out before the build dies:

```
    ...
[DEBUG]    org.springmodules:spring-modules-cache:jar:0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       opensymphony:oscache:jar:2.3:compile
[DEBUG]       tangosol:tangosol-coherence:jar:3.3-rc1:compile
[DEBUG]       oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.jcs:jcs:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          concurrent:concurrent:jar:1.0:compile
    ...
```

better answers are welcome.

Comment: Sweet this does work.  Note that the "errant" dependency might be located in the heart of the output, not necessarily at the end when the exception is reported :|

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why maven didn't download the required dependency from the MAVEN CENTRAL REPO , if it is not available in your local repository.

mvn dependency:tree is useful to see the hierarchy , that means it can tell you which jar will depend on which others jars.

So, what i can guess from here is that required jar `tangosol-coherence` is missing in  your internal nexus repository. i.e

```
http://mvnrepo.initech.com/archiva/repository/initechrepo
```

So, to overcome this problem either you have to install the required jar in your internal nexus repository or as a temporary solution you can download that jar and put it into your local system repository, so that you can have a successful build.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I knew all that. The question is how can I find out which artifact is depending on it.