# maven failing on dependency that isn't actually in the project

Tags: maven

My build is failing with this error message (corporate stuff crossed out):

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XXXX: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project XXXX: The following artifacts could not be
>   resolved:
>   com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:jar:0.9.3,
>   com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:jar:0.2.0: Cannot
>   access XXXX-release (http://repo.XXXX.corp/main/repo) in offline mode
>   and the artifact
>   com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:jar:0.9.3 has not
>   been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]

The funny thing is that `actionbarpulltorefresh` is not a dependency of this project. I double-checked and the string appears nowhere in the directory. It's a dependency of another project I built a couple of days ago, but not this one. It's also not mentioned in my users's settings.xml file, or anywhere in .m2 except that it's actually installed there.

Where could that error possibly be coming from?

Comment: Also that other project for which this is a dependency builds fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a transitive dependency, a dependency of a dependency.

This question might help you: [How to determine which Maven dependency is needing a missing dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978768/how-to-determine-which-maven-dependency-is-needing-a-missing-dependency)

Comment: There was a bit more too it. My maven build references an artifact which is a Gradle build with Gradle dependencies (installed to Maven Central). The Maven build, when pulling in that dependency, ended up looking for com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:jar, when the real artifact is an aar (Android Archive). Somehow the artifact packaging is getting lost in translation.